# Run a ruby on rails job every night at a specific time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, jobs

I have a job like this :

```
class LdapSyncJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  require 'pp'
  def perform
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|
      user.update("Do something")
    end
  end
end
```

and I use delayed job for the job processing .
My question is how and where to define my job to be run every night at a specific time ? 
Should I call my job in an action or not ? if so how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delayed job mainly used for processing tasks in queue and in background. It's usually not preferred for scheduling of tasks.

For your use case you should check out [whenever](https://rubygems.org/gems/whenever/versions/0.9.7) a ruby gem, which works with cron jobs to schedule tasks repeatedly.

I would suggest you to move logic or method call `LdapSyncJob.perform()` to rake task.

In config/schedule.rb, you can do something this way

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "#{@pre_set_variables[:environment]}"

env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")

set :output, "/logs/cron_log_#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log"

every 1.day, :at => '02:30 am' do
    command "cd #{Rails.root}/lib/tasks && rake task_calls_peform_code"
end
```

Note : Don't forget to update and restart crontab using belong commands.

```
whenever --update-crontab app --set 'environment=production' #update crontab
service crond restart #restart crontab
```

Comment: you mean some thing like this in my schedule.rb    (( every 1.hours  do 
  LdapSyncJob.perform() end   )) But it didn't work.

Comment: This works fine but I used crono gem which was easier